# Time complexity of O(n) inside O(logn) outer loop

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of this algorithm. A is an array input. The code does not run, by the way, it is for demonstrative purposes.

```
def func(A):
    result = 0
    n = len(A)
    while n > 1:
        n = n/2
        result = result + min(A[1,...,n])
    return result
```

This assumes array A is of length n.

I would assume the time complexity of this to be O(n(log n)), as the while loop has complexity O(log n), and the min function has complexity O(n). However, this function is apparently of complexity O(n) not O(n(log n)). I am wondering how this could be?

Comment: this code *compiles* just fine. If you tried to run it, it may or may not throw a runtime error, depending on what you pass to `func`

Comment: @MadPhysicist but it will be wrong, `A[:n]` is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to show that it was finding the minimum of the halved array, not the entirety of A, with each iteration. I am not particularly concerned with the code itself, I just made this code to put forth the idea of what I was trying to show.

Comment: @AndrewZaw what does "apparently" mean?

Comment: @khachik According to my teacher this sort of algorithm would be O(n). I am having difficulty understanding how this is so.

Comment: What kind of array is A? Is it a Numpy array? You're using strange syntax in that `min` call if it's supposed to be a 1D array. Or is that supposed to be pseudocode?

Comment: @AndrewZaw Have you studied series, say in a Calc 2 class? That's not exactly the answer to your question, but it might help you build intuition for this sort of thing. Big O notation is about what happens when you make n arbitrarily large.

Comment: @PM2Ring That is utterly irrelevant to the theoretical question OP is asking.

Comment: @TagoreSmith True, the type of the array has little relevance to the complexity. But a question should be clear, and as it's currently written it's not clear that that line is pseudocode. Readers should not have to guess such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The total number of iterations you get linearly depends on n. it is n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... = n(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...) and this is what O(n) denotes.

Comment: I think that's incorrect/incomplete analysis. You should explain how many terms there are in the the series (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ...). If there are f(n) terms (and there are actually log(n) terms) that expression could evaluate to some g(n), making the final big O greater than O(n). Luckily, this series evaluates to 1 for an infinite number of terms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) so the final result is `n * <some number less than 1>`, therefore O(n).

Comment: It's probably worth noting that for small n (and all practical n is small n in practice) this does look more like n log n than n.

Comment: And... in practice O(n log n) is usually fine where O(n) is, even where performance is a concern. I ran into this today, where I could have merged two sorted lists using an O(n) algorithm but instead concatenated them and sorted. Doing so made the code dead simple, and that sort is not currently even close to being the bottleneck. If I ever optimize to the point that it is I'll re-write it, but I prefer simplicity to performance where performance doesn't matter much.

Comment: It's good to understand the theoretical complexity of your code. It's also important to understand what that means in practice.

Comment: @slider I assumed even with basic math background it is clear that the series converges to one, but good point.